# How to check entire hard disk for errors and bad sectors

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks

I may be misunderstanding some concepts here, but as far as I know, each disk has a partition table and actual partitions.

I'm looking to test a hard drive for bad sectors and errors, but the tools I found to do this are meant for partitions -- not disks. `badblocks` takes a partition `/dev/sda1` not `/dev/sda`. Same story with `e2fsck`.

As far as I understand, those tools only test space assigned to partitions, not a whole disk. Is there any way to test an entire disk?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any way to test whole disk?

Yes, using `badblocks`:

```
badblocks /dev/sda
```

The manpage refers to partitions because `badblocks` can tell `mkfs.ext2` about the bad blocks it finds, and that only works when checking partitions. But `badblocks` itself works fine on full disks.

However `badblocks` is really a relic of a bygone era when hard drives didn’t manage their bad blocks themselves. Nowadays drives track errors themselves and are capable of remapping bad sectors as circumstances allow (typically, when a bad sector is rewritten). You’re probably better off running SMART tests and checking the results:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
smartctl -t offline /dev/sda
smartctl -x /dev/sda
```

(make sure each test completes before running the next one).

Comment: I get `badblocks invalid starting block (0)` error on this. Found on internet its due I did not supply partition.

Comment: @Gacek Just omit the `first_block` argument. `badblocks` will start from the beginning of the disk by default.

Comment: @Gacek It's not mentioned anywhere in the `badblocks` manpage that it only works with partitions, but not full disks. With that being said, I would not rely on `badblocks`: I just run it on an old broken disk both in its read-only and in its read/write mode and it was NOT able to find any bad blocks; but running an actual OS on it failed almost immediately -- it probably has to do with the real-life access pattern which `badblocks` doesn't try to emulate.

Comment: my badblocks was being blocked by other test, thats why i had that error. I will try smartctl and return :)

Comment: Modern drives hide badblocks. I thought you need to ask SMART, to tell you the health of the device. Does badblocks talk to SMART?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor they hide them up to a point — a failed block will still cause read errors. `badblocks` doesn’t talk to SMART.

Comment: It looks like `smartctl` does not have a progress functionality. But we can accompany its progress with a command like:  `while true; do clear; sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda; sudo smartctl -c /dev/sda | head -11 | tail -3; sleep 5; done`

Comment: or, if you only want to check the current test progress and not do a selftest, try this: `while true; do clear; sudo smartctl -c /dev/sda | head -11 | tail -3; sleep 5; done`